# Could not generate migration classes from difference (Zend Framework 1.10 + Doctrine 1.2.2)

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I'm trying to perform database migration from the command line using
"php doctrine generate-migrations-diff", it just gives me the error:

"Could not generate migration classes from difference"

Is there anyone having the same issue?

I'm using Zend Framework + Doctrine 1.2.2

Thanks.

Comment: you have changed the schema.yml and then enter this command?

Answer (score 1):

It means there is no difference between yaml files and your models. It is perfectly fine.

Comment: However, this is not always the case. If you have made changes to the schema, rebuilt your model then tried to run generate-migrations-diff, you may get this error as well. You have to remove all classes associated to your new schema entry before running the diff. You should always 1. Make changes to the schema 2. Run migrations-diff 3. Build the model.

Comment: http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/symfony-could-not-generate-migration-classes-from-difference